# QueryDSL request with parameters, is it possible?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, querydsl

In SQL it is very simple to make parameterized query using string concatenation. Example, where I'm getting necessary columns from the DB table according preset parameters (strings with columns' names)

```
String id_column = "id", city_column = "city", streetname_column ="streetname", housenumber_column = "housenumber"; //Parameters
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT "+id_column+","+streetname_column+" FROM address" ); //How do the same in QueryDSL?
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        for (int i = 0; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
            System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(i+1)+" ");
        }
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
                System.out.print(
                        rs.getString(rsmd.getColumnName(i+1)) + " "
                );
            }
        }
```

How can i do the same with this (you also can make your own example) QueryDSL request:

```
List<Address> q1=queryFactory.selectFrom(address)
                    .fetch();
```

In this query I am getting whole table.

Comment: Your example of concatenating Strings to build a query is really bad. `PreparedStatement` is the way to go to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @kayaman and can I do `PreparedStatement` in QueryDSL?

Comment: @Kayaman , I have already read lots of documentation and I still hadn't found how I can select arbitrary tables and columns according my JSON parameters from e.g. my front-end. It will be very helpful, if you share to me a link with these abilities description.

Comment: Sounds like QueryDSL has some bad documentation then. Considering that QueryDSL is built for "selecting arbirary tables and columns" it's odd that their documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Kayaman ok, thanks, and can you give a link to such abilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found an answer. The solution is located at this page:
[Examples of using play.db.jpa.JPAApi](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA#Examples:)

And in the context of my question, solution is following:

```
package controllers;
import play.db.jpa.JPAApi;
import play.db.jpa.Transactional;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestingReportsDep{

private JPAApi jpaApi;
@Inject
public TestingReportsDep(JPAApi jpaApi) {
    this.jpaApi = jpaApi;
}
Object[] tempObj;

@Transactional
public void resolving_requests) {
    String id_column = "id", city_column = "city", streetname_column ="streetname", housenumber_column = "housenumber"; //Parameters
    String request="SELECT "+id_column+","+streetname_column+" FROM address;";
    jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(request);
        int ResultsAmount = query.getResultList().size();
        List Result = query.getResultList();
        System.out.print("\n\n\nNew super query by Bogdan:\n");

        for(int i=0; i< ResultsAmount; i++){
            tempObj = (Object[]) Result.get(i);

            System.out.print(tempObj[0]+" "+tempObj[1]+"\n");
        }
        return null;
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, you're not using Querydsl but building a native query !